# LinkedIn Thumbnail problems

Tags: hyperlink, linkedin-api, thumbnails, preview

When uploading my portfolio, from Cargo, to LinkedIn the thumbnail image is incorrect. The thumbnail is correct elsewhere - such as when sending the link over text message. But when I upload the link to post on LinkedIn the thumbnail is incorrect. Everything looks good on my web builder view. Help :-)

I tried deleting a previous post including the portfolio link with the old thumbnail thinking the old post was swaying the thumbnails preview image. That did not work.